# Printing numbers using 5 multithread

Tags: java, multithreading, list, for-loop, numbers

I want to print a list of a number using multithreaded

```
    class RunnableWorker implements Runnable{
    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 30000; i++) {
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + ": " + i);
        }
    }
    
}
public class RunnableFunctionalInterfaceDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r3 = new RunnableWorker();     
        Thread t3 = new Thread(r3);
        t3.start();
    }
}
```

thread 1   thread2 ......
1          2

Comment: And what is your problem?

Comment: Read our [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) page and [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65691115/edit)  your question to improve it. Good questions tend to receive quicker, better answers from the community.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what your problem is, but you just need to create more threads, if that is what you want.

```
 Runnable r3 = new RunnableWorker();
    Thread t0 = new Thread(r3);
    Thread t1 = new Thread(r3);
    Thread t2 = new Thread(r3);
    Thread t3 = new Thread(r3);
    Thread t4 = new Thread(r3);
    t0.start();
    t1.start();
    t2.start();
    t3.start();
    t4.start();
```

how ever, this will call a new instance of the method run for every thread.

Looking at the Executor pool

```
class WorkerThread implements Runnable {
private String message;
public WorkerThread(String s){
    this.message=s;
}
public void run() {
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" || Counter: "+message);
}
```

}

```
  import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
    import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

    public class RunnableFunctionalInterfaceDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);//creating a pool of 4 threads
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            Runnable worker = new WorkerThread("" + i);
          executor.execute(worker);//calling execute method of ExecutorService
        }
        executor.shutdown();
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to print it out without duplication when I use the all-thread print from 0 - 30000

I want to print out just like this


thread 1..........thread 2..........thread3.........thread4........thread5
1......................2.....................3..................4....................5
6........................7.................8.......................9..................10

Comment: You should look up the Executor threadpool!